# Чем отличается запрос от SQL-инструкции?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Читаю в книге: 
Инструкции `SELECT` - это запросы SQL. 
Запрос - какая-либо инструкция SQL. Однако чаще всего этот термин используют по отношению к инструкциям `SELECT`.

Как понять инструкции `SELECT`?
1. `SELECT * FROM table_name;` - это запрос?
2. `SELECT 6 * 2;` - или это запрос? 
3. `SELECT` - это запрос? ведь же инструкция `SELECT` или под инструкцией `SELECT` подразумевается полноценный запрос?

Comment: *Запрос - какая-либо инструкция SQL.* Предполагается - синтаксически корректная инструкция. 1) Да. 2) Да (если сервер не против, иначе добавить FROM DUAL). 3) Syntax error. Это косяк, а не запрос...

Comment: А где собственно `подзапросы` в вашем вопросе?

Comment: @4per я тольк начал их разбирать не очень понятно что за SQL инструкция, почему инструкция SELECT это запросы в SQL? и тд

Comment: а ещё есть [операторы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B). в общем, бардак в терминологии (кстати, и в англоязычной, по-моему, не лучше). @Mike, так что не берите дурного в голову и не пытайтесь извлечь какой-то особый смысл из самих терминов. термины — это вообще, как и любые слова, — всего лишь «разноцветные ярлычки, кем-то куда-то когда-то зачем-то наклеенные».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инструкция - это то, что можно выполнить. В контексте SQL инструкция - это полноценный SQL-запрос.

Инструкция SELECT - это SQL-запрос, содержащий конструкцию SELECT со всеми необходимыми параметрами и/или дополнительными ключевыми словами.

Comment: `DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t2)`. "SELECT со всеми необходимыми параметрами и/или дополнительными ключевыми словами" - в наличии... ещё мутнее, если приводить варианты с CTE - но это не для формата комментария. Но если @MikeMclaren принял - пусть будет так.

Comment: @Akina, хороший пример с DELETE ). А с CTE не вижу проблемы, т.к. это доп.параметры SELECT'а

Comment: Представь - селект в СТЕ, и его апдейт в основном... и наоборот...

Comment: Или совсем экзотика - UPDATE с RETURNING/OUTPUT - это же SELECT?

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу разницы между термином `запрос` и `sql-инструкция`. При этом в устной речи я употребляю только `запрос`. Если я хочу подчеркнуть, что запрос типа `select` то я скажу `select`, `запрос на выборку`, `выборка`. Если я хочу подчеркнуть, что запрос другого типа скажу `delete(-запрос)`, `update(-запрос)`, `insert(-запрос)` или же `dml-инструкция`, `ddl-инструкция`.

Comment: SQL-инструкция - это не всегда запрос. Например, итератор в ХП - это инструкция.